# Is there any limit on the number of product attributes which can be made is_filterable_in_search = 1 in Magento?

Tags: magento-enterprise, catalogsearch, solr, enterprise-1.10

We are using Magento Enterprise 1.10 and SOLR as our catalog search engine.

We are facing one major issue in our live website is that whenever we start increasing number of search filterable attributes in our system, after certain limit catalog search breaks. It gives no search result.

I tried to look at the Magento exception logs it says:-

```
2014-12-16T21:07:53+00:00 ERR (3): exception 'Exception' with message '"400" Status: Bad Request' in /var/www/site/lib/Apache/Solr/Service.php:334
```

I tried to log the URL request made by Magento to SOLR during catalog search & it basically makes 3 request to SOLR and in the third request it has huge number of parameters in facet.field request URL.

I tried to copy the third request URL and hit it in browser but it does not gives any `JSON` response, it gives error **HTTP Status code 400 Bad Request**.

What could be the possible issue ?

Is there any limitation on no. of facet.field request made by Magento to SOLR

Is there some configuration changes is required on Magento or SOLR side to fix this issue ?

Comment: When Solr is throwing the error it should usually log something in its own logfile. Not the one from Magento. Can you post the message which is in there over here?

Comment: @zafar did you get a resolution to this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be hitting your web server's upper request line/header limit.

You might want to take a look at:

**Nginx:**
[large_client_header_buffers](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#large_client_header_buffers)

**Apache:** [LimitRequestLine](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestline)

Failing that, it seems like something you could contact Enterprise support about. They may have a patch for this already that allows you to send larger data.